# Burninate the [gcloud] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcloud) tag is described as related to the `gcloud` command line utility. This doesn't look like a good tag for Stack Overflow. Possibly much better for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour).

Also it is confusing (at least I confused it :)) that it is about [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) which has its own tag.

Answer (score 4):

The tag wiki clearly describes what this tag stands for, so no confusion here.

Futhermore, most of these questions seem to be on-topic on SO while some of them are on-topic for `Server Fault` too; these two sites are not mutual exclusive, and never was.

Lets take a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/275923).

1. The tag is descriptive and non-unambiguous.
2. It is on-topic, in general.
3. It is useful because it marks question related to a particular tool.
4. It stays for the same thing in the properly tagged questions.

This tag seems to take the right place where it currently is. We should not burninate it.

Comment: ok, I see your point, especially `these two sites are not mutual exclusive, and never was` is something i have to think about. So although a number of questions with the tag are in my opinion not suitable for stackoverflow, there are also a lot of valid questions and I'm willing to withdrawn  my burnination suggestion. Should I delete the question or leave it for future reference?

Comment: @akostadinov I would leave it as it is, we can gather more opinions and probably learn something new about SE.